# ElasticSearch: Partial Update a document or remove it. (Opposite of upsert)

Tags: elasticsearch

In ElasticSearch I'm using upsert to update a document that may not exist:

```
POST /website/pageviews/1/_update
{
   "script" : "ctx._source.online+=1",
   "upsert": {
       "online": 1
   }
}
```

Since my data are going to change frequently I want to remove my document if `online == 0`.

It would be useless to use `update` if I need to get the document and check `online` value every time, and I don't want to accumulate a lot of trash documents.

Which is the best way to remove my document when `online == 0`? Something like:

```
POST /website/pageviews/1/_update
{
   "script" : "ctx._source.online-=1",
   "remove_doc": "ctx._source.online == 0"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`delete` operation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#_scripted_updates) like this:

```
POST /website/pageviews/1/_update
{
   "script" : "if (online == 0) { ctx.op = 'delete' } else { ctx._source.online += 1 }",
   "upsert": {
       "online": 1
   }
}
```